# URL path redirects to a single php file

Tags: php, javascript, http, url

Want to know if it is possible to get different URL paths to redirect to a single php file which i can pull the name from the URL.

i.e. If i have www.example.com/username or www.example.com/username2 or www.example.com/username3

I want it to redirect to a username.php file which then i can get the username from the URL and load the information from the database.

If not does anyone have any ideas on how i can do something similar. tumblr do something similar as u can just type in a user-name in the url and it loads their blog.

Comment: you can do URL rewriting for that.

Comment: As the person above me said, it can be done using rewriting.  This will be web server specific though, so what web server are you using?

Comment: i am using a apache server, do i put it in the .htaccess file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course it's possible thanks to URL rewriting! Check out [Apache mod rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

For your information, a rewrite rule like you want may look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/username(.*) /username.php?user=username$1 [QSA,L]
```

I'm pretty sure this will work. Just activate the mod_rewrite in your server.

Comment: got it : 

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule page(.*) index.php?user=username$1 [QSA,L]

meaning : www.example.com/page - get redirected

-----------

RewriteRule ^page/(.*) /index.php?username=$1 [QSA,L] - gets www.example.com/page/username

Comment: Perfect (even though your solution in your comment isn't exactly what you asked for, my answer helped you to be on the right track, it's the most important ;) )

Answer (score 0):

when u want to open `www.example.com/page/username`
web server will redirect to `www.example.com/index.php?username=username1`
with that you can give a page to each user

actually they are pages like

```
www.example.com/index.php?username=username1
www.example.com/index.php?username=username2
www.example.com/index.php?username=username3
```

with rewrite engine they can be accessible like this.

```
www.example.com/page/username
www.example.com/page/username2
www.example.com/page/username3
```

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/(.*) /index.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: ahhh i understand. Thanks for your help.. ill let you know if i get it working

Comment: i have put the following in the .htaccess file :

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/(.*) index.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]

but it doesnt load the css for the index file, am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: Jason can you clarify more? I need real php file to see problem if possible a working place

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is called a FrontController Pattern and is usually achieved with a rewrite-rule. An example for a slightly different method for Apache2 would be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName quickstart.local
  DocumentRoot /path/to/quickstart/public

  SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

  <Directory /path/to/quickstart/public>
      DirectoryIndex index.php
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This one is taken from the [Zend Framework Manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html), where you find a practical example of the [FrontController Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern). Basically, all requests are send to one file (in this example `index.php`) and handled from there, usually by routing the request to another controller.

Comment: how it works in terms of the provided configuration? which line is responsible for routing user's request to your patterns, controllers and other cool stuff?

Comment: how about editing my answer to your liking? That way we can get rid of these pointless discussions and I don't feel stalked by you. ;)

Comment: I can't edit the answer I don't understand. So, I asked for a clarification.